# ReactJS is it possible to render a string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a code that returns a string, but since it's on render it needs to be accompanied by an HTML tag, in this case span.

I want to use this code in multiple places including placeholders and labels, but with span, I believe that's impossible.

Here's the code in question, would appreciate some ideas on how to fix.

```
let LocalizedString = React.createClass({
 render: function() {

    if (!this.getKey(loadLang, this.props.xlKey)) {
        return <span>{this.props.xlKey + ' untranslated in ' + userLang + ' JSON'}</span>;
    } else {
        return <span>{this.getKey(loadLang, this.props.xlKey)}</span>;
    }
},

getKey: function(obj, str) {
    str = str.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // let's convert indexes to properties
    str = str.replace(/^\./, ''); // gets rid of leading dot

    let a = str.split('.');

    for (let i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
        let key = a[i];

        if (key in obj) {
            obj = obj[key];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return obj;
},
});

module.exports = LocalizedString;
```

In another file that calls LocalizedString, I have this, but  makes placeholder return undefined...

```
<TextField alert={alerts.username} onChange={this._onChangeUsername} placeholder={<LocalizedString xlKey='pages.signin.general.username'/>} ref="username" value={this.props.username}/>
```

Bottom line is pretty much, can I make render return just a string without any tags or make placeholder accept and discard the span tag?

Regards.

Comment: AFAIK no. But why does `LocalizedString` have to be a React component at all?

Comment: Work crew asked me to redo my original code, which was just a function call into a component for better accessibility... because typing in getKey('keyname') was too much, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use a `function` instead of a `React Component` as per the requirement.

React Component's `render` method must be bound to return `single wrapped markup` or essentially a `Virtual DOM`.